# Is there a command to refresh the applications listed on the Dash?

Tags: unity, gnome, unity-dash

Sometimes, after installing an application (Codeweavers Crossover to be more specific on this case) it fails to show on the Dash until you logout and back on. That happens with Unity and GNOME Shell, remember that with GNOME Fallback it is automatically added as a menu.

Is there a command that allows one to force a refresh on the cached application launchers in the Unity Dash or the GNOME Shell desktop environments?

Answer (score 8):

To restart the GNOME Shell (no logout):
Press ALT + F2 and type `r` or `restart` and press enter

To restart Unity (no logout):
Press ALT + F2 and type `setsid unity` or `unity --replace`

Comment: I don't know if anything changed in UNITY, but `setsid unity` just closes it, and `unity --replace` closes it and restarts it (both close your unsaved programs in the process). `restart` is not a known command. I also had to use the terminal as none of the commands did anything in alt+F2