# Command line command to refresh GUI desktop, like when pressing F5?

Tags: command-line, shortcut-keys, desktop-environments, filemanager

Is there any command to refresh the desktop icons (exactly like F5 button does)?

I need this because in Startup Applications I set a command to mount my backup partition and I've created a desktop link to some directories there. The problem is that the icons are not refreshed when I log in, unless I press F5. I would like to put a command in the Startup Applications to do so. (note that I don't want to restart the GNOME shell or Unity, like they said [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/262472/is-there-a-command-to-refresh-the-applications-listed-on-the-dash). I just need a command to do exactly what F5 does)

Comment: I don't think this is possible as F5 is something that is captured by Nautilus. It's not a command AFAIK.

Comment: Think restarting Nautilus (instead of Unity) could help? http://askubuntu.com/questions/498914/reload-the-list-of-bookmarks-in-files-nautilus

Comment: As a workaround, would it be acceptable to automatically *create* the shorcuts after connection is established?

Comment: muru, restarting Nautilus worked just fine!
It`s probably not the most efficient way, but it certainly did what I wanted, thanks a lot.

Comment: Maybe You might try this one as well ~$ xrefresh

Comment: @muru Per Eduardo's comment above, could you add that as an answer? Thanks!

Comment: @Seth Posted, as requested.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If refreshing is tricky, we can restart Nautilus:

```
pkill nautilus
nautilus -n
```

Your Startup Applications entry can be easily modified to add these commands as well, as part of script, by chaining:

```
udisks --mount  ... && pkill -u nautilus && nautilus -n
```

Nautilus has a `-q` option to make it quit by itself, but this doesn't [work well](https://askubuntu.com/a/499015/158442) with `nautilus -n`.

Answer (score 6):

You could emulate pressing the key with [`xdotool`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/xdotool.1.html), if you can not find how to directly call the function it is mapped to:

```
xdotool key F5
```

The difficult part is to do that when the current window is not the desktop.
It should be possible to find it with th `search` command - but may need some experimenting;

First, try to find the right window, using getwindowname to show the title of matched windows:

```
xdotool search --class Desktop getwindowname
```

If the result looks right, try:

```
xdotool search --class Desktop key F5
```

Otherwise, see [`man xdotool`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/xdotool.1.html) for many more options of `xdotool search`.
If you need more information about the existing windows to make it work, these commands are the most useful for inspecting them: [`xwininfo`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/xwininfo.1.html) and [`xprop`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/xprop.1.html).

Comment: You could use `xdotool` to type in the shortcut for minimize all windows (Super-D ?) and then use it type in `F5`.

Comment: Volker Siegel, the getwindowname didn`t worked. It simply executes and shows no message (same when trying the third command, with Desktop key). I tried xwininfo and xprop and they didn`t give me any useful information for this case. Still, I tried xdotool key F5. On the command line, obviously was just like pressing F5 on the command line and not on the Desktop; on the Startup Apps, it did nothing, probably because he`s still not on the Desktop window by the time he executes the command.
The solution that worked with me was the one 'muru' gave on the comments: restarting Nautilus
Thanks anyway

Comment: @muru I agree, restarting nautilus is much better for your case. I leave this answer here because it is useful for others with similar cases when it's not possible to restart. And yes, it's difficult to find the right search pattern for the window;

Answer (score 1):

There is one stupid, but simple solution (and it works). You can **cd** to Desktop and then *create and remove some temporary folder* in terminal. That will trigger refresh action on Desktop.

`mkdir some_folder_name && rm -rf some_folder_name`