# What command will refresh the menu of a GNOME Dash application?

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell

I have modified the `.desktop` file of an application that appears in the GNOME Dash. This should change the options that appear in the application's right-click menu, but to see the changes I have log out and in again.

I have tried running `restart` in the <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> dialog, [as suggested in another Dash-related question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/262472/is-there-a-command-to-refresh-the-applications-listed-on-the-dash), but this does not refresh the application menus.

What command will refresh the menus?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Restarting the desktop shell with <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> then `restart` will indeed refresh application menus in the dash.

(I had an error in my `.desktop` file that made it look like nothing was happening.)

Comment: In principle, the Gnome Dash will refresh automatically if you add a desktop file. Indeed, it might be possible you need to restart the shell if the contents of an existing .desktop file has changed.